# Controller action is not being called after middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've been trying to get this to work, but no luck.

I have middleware class where used to verify uploaded files.

But after middleware, controller action is not firing.

If anyone here can help me out or point me in a direction, that would be greatly appreciated. It's almost midnight on my side, and I'm about to give up.

Here is the middleware class:

```
public class UploadMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    private const uint FMFD_RETURNUPDATEDIMGMIMES = 0x20;
    private const uint RESERVED = 0;
    private const string UNKNOWN = "unknown/unknown";
    private const uint S_OK = 0;
    public UploadMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var authToken = context.Request.Headers["id"].ToString();
        var path = context.Request.Path.ToString();

            if (authToken != String.Empty)
            {
                if (!IsMultipartContentType(context.Request.ContentType))
                {
                    await _next(context);
                    return;
                }

                var boundary = GetBoundary(context.Request.ContentType);
                var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, context.Request.Body);
                var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
                var buffer = new byte[256];
                while (section != null)
                {

                    var fileName = GetFileName(section.ContentDisposition);
                    var bytesRead = 0;
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Append))
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            bytesRead = await section.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));

                        } while (bytesRead < 0);
                    }
                    if (!verifyUpcomingFiles(buffer))
                    {
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Undefined file type detected.");
                    }
                    // else
                    // {
                    //     await _next(context);

                    // }

                    section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
                }
                // await _next(context);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are not allowed to complete this process.");

            }

    }
```

Startup.cs class

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }


        app.UseStaticFiles();


            app.UseUploadMiddleware();
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


        });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting `await _next(context);`

Comment: Hi @IvanMladenov thanks for the response. Yes I have tried.

Comment: And what happens ? Could you give more information on the exact execution that happens ?

Comment: @IvanMladenov, I have debugged but nothing happens, I've posted a file on `localhost:5000/Upload/Process` but it is not go through to the target action after middleware.

Comment: Does it get to ` await _next(context);` ? What happens ?

Comment: Yes it is. But after `await _next(context)` the Upload/Process action is not firing.

Comment: Do you get an exception that it cannot map to a route or it goes to some other action ?

Comment: @IvanMladenov no i dont get any exception, request is ending after middleware.